# How do i mock the behavior of a void method when unit testing my delete service?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I'm currently unit testing the endpoints of a Spring Boot CRUD RESTful API and i have the following **"Delete user by its id"** endpoint that's composed of a **controller** and a **service** to implement its logic :

Delete controller (it's mainly calling the logic of the service and defining some guidelines) :

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
    public class DeleteUserController {

        @Autowired
        DeleteUserService service;

        @DeleteMapping
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
        public void deleteUser_whenDeleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
            service.deleteUser(id);
        }
    }
```

Delete service :

```
@Service
public class DeleteUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {

        repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));

        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

While everything seems to be working fine until now, i'd be grateful if someone could tell me what i could improve in the code above. Anyways, My controllers unit test is the problem i can't seem to solve :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DeleteUserService.class)
public class DeleteUserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DeleteUserService deleteUserService;

    @Test
    public void removeUserById_whenDeleteMethod() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test Name");
        user.setId(89L);

        doNothing().when(deleteUserService).deleteUser(user.getId());

        mvc.perform(delete("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
    }
```

I'm getting a ***java.lang.AssertionError: Status*** because while the code is expecting to get a *204 No content* response status, it's receiving a *404 Not found* which means it's throwing the exception that's supposed to throw when the user doesn't exist.

I think the answer is in the way i need to mock the behavior of my services logic, but i have no idea how. Would appreciate if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: Does the user you're trying to delete exist? I see you creating a user, but the user needs to be in the repository, otherwise it's just a local `User` w/ no presence anywhere except that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebMVC test layer is not configured to include the controller under test; `DeleteUserController`. The 404 refers to the missing requestmapping instead of a functional user not found. Use `@WebMvcTest(DeleteUserController.class)` instead of `@WebMvcTest(DeleteUserService.class)`.